# How do I remove certain character in a string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace

Is there a method to do so? This is the code I have written. Also, I am using the latest
version of Python:

```
import string

Finn = "It's Adventure Time!"
punctuation = string.punctuation
print(punctuation)
for punc in punctuation:
   if punc in Finn:
       Finn[18] = ' '
print(Finn)
```

Error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are expecting this:

```
import string

Finn = "It's Adventure Time!"
punctuation = string.punctuation
print(punctuation)
for punc in punctuation:
   if punc in Finn:
       Finn = Finn.replace(punc, "")

print(Finn)
```

Comment: The `if punc in Finn` shouldn't be necessary :)

Comment: @DaveJ, yeah.. you are right.. I tried to keep his code unchanged as far as I can

Answer (score 0):

One very short variant is:

```
import string

finn = "It's Adventure Time!"
print(finn)
table = str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)
finn = finn.translate(table)
print(finn)
```

This solution requires python 3. (As tagged in the OP)

Comment: Its giving an error "AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'"

Comment: @AerofoilKite: are you using python3? It works for me.

Comment: Oh!! I'm using python 2.7; Probably you should mention the version in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shortest one, I can think of :P

```
import string
finn = "It's Adventure Time!"
finn = ''.join(i for i in finn if i not in string.punctuation)
```